# Oracle HCM REST API - get query with '&' query param

Tags: oracle, rest

I am trying to get organizations resource for Name = 'G&A' using the following API

https://xxx/hcmCoreSetupApi/resources/11.13.18.02/organizations/?onlyData=true&q=Name='G&A'

But getting an error "URL request parameter A' cannot be used in this context."

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand `&` character is used as a separator between query parameters. If you want to pass an ampersand as part of a query parameter's value then use the equivalent hexidecimal code `%26` instead of `&`:

```
https://xxx/hcmCoreSetupApi/resources/11.13.18.02/organizations/?onlyData=true&q=Name='G%26A'
```

However, that is still invalid as you have too many equals `=` characters in that string; so did you intend to have three parameters named `onlyData`, `q` and `Name`? Then you would encode them like this:

```
https://xxx/hcmCoreSetupApi/resources/11.13.18.02/organizations/?onlyData=true&q=&Name='G%26A'
```

Or, if you really had intended to have two parameters named `onlyData`, `q=Name` then you would need to encode the equals `=` character in the parameter name as well:

```
https://xxx/hcmCoreSetupApi/resources/11.13.18.02/organizations/?onlyData=true&q%3DName='G%26A'
```

Or, if `Name=` is part of the value not the key then:

```
https://xxx/hcmCoreSetupApi/resources/11.13.18.02/organizations/?onlyData=true&q=Name%3D'G%26A'
```